`cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed` coming from child bottom modal sheet
I have parent Widget A.
And from there I have several WidgetB in ListView.
And If I press button in WidgetB, I show bottomModalSheet.
 showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor:
          isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.grey.shade900 : Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      context: context,
      builder: (scontext) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(scontext)
              .copyWith(textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(1.0)),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: size.height * 0.8,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: ref
                  .read(commentProvider.notifier)
                  .fetchAllCommentsUI(widget.diary.diaryId),
              builder: (tcontext, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<CommentModel> commentList = snapshot.data!;
                  return CommentScreen(
                    size: size,
                    commentsList: commentList,
                    diaryModel: widget.diary,
                    addCommentCount: addCommentCount,
                    deleteCommentCount: deleteCommentCount,
                  );
                } else {
                  return const SkeletonComments();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

But when Widget A is resumed, I reset data in ListView once again.
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _completeLoading = false;
        });
        resumePage();
      }
    }
  }

resumePage() fetch data once again from scratch.
But the case that user open bottomModalSheet, screen is resumed, it throws error:
-> cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed.
I'm not clear whether that 'ref' here means parent widget's state is changed.
And how to deal this this problem.
The problem is caused from  future: ref .read(commentProvider.notifier) .fetchAllCommentsUI(widget.diary.diaryId), part in FutureBuilder of showModalBottomSheet.
